# Switch href link of button, depends on website language by JS

Tags: javascript, multilingual

I have a button on a website, I translated the text (using po and mo files), but the link is still only one. I'm trying to switch that depends on in what language website is open, but my code doesn't work. May anybody please help

```
function changeLink(document.getAttribute("lang")){
var theLink = document.querySelector('.donate-now');
    if(document.getAttribute("lang") == 'en-EN'){
        theLink.href="https://usrussiacc.org/membership/";   
    } else if(document.getAttribute("lang") == 'ru-RU'){
        theLink.href="https://usrussiacc.org/ru/glavnaja/chlenstvo/"; 
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this code runs when attribute already exists on document?

Comment: the function definition is a little weird. Normally, you'd call the function somewhere like changeLink(document.getAttribute("lang")) and declare the function like, 

function changeLink(lang) { }

Comment: Did you tried console.log(document.getAttribute("lang")) ? Are you sure about that the lang attr is equal to 'en-EN' or 'ru-RU'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I assume you are setting `<html lang="en-EN">`.

`<html>` is actually the **Root Element** of document. It needs to be retrieved as such; the easiest and quickest way is `document.documentElement` ([MDS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/documentElement)).

Using this, we call `document.documentElement.getAttribute("lang")` to retrieve the `lang="aa-AA"` attribute off the `<html>` tag.

I've also cleaned up the function, and called it separately.

```js
function changeLink(lang) {
  var theLink = document.querySelector('.donate-now');
  if (lang == 'en-EN') {
    console.log('en-EN')
    theLink.href = "https://usrussiacc.org/membership/";
  } else if (lang == 'ru-RU') {
    console.log('ru-RU')
    theLink.href = "https://usrussiacc.org/ru/glavnaja/chlenstvo/";
  } else {
    console.log('neither')
  }
}

changeLink(document.documentElement.getAttribute("lang"))
```

```html
<html lang="en-EN">

<head></head>

<body>
  <a href="" class="donate-now">I'm a link</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Although the above code is still not very scalable, or friendly. Below I've rewritten it, to make it more scalable and reusable. Also removed the need for an argument all together. Just add more lang/path pairs to `listURI`, and it will automatically handle them. You could also put in a generic URI, in case the given language doesn't exist (never trust users).

```js
function changeLink() {
  let listURI = {
    'en-EN': 'https://usrussiacc.org/membership/',
    'ru-RU': 'https://usrussiacc.org/ru/glavnaja/chlenstvo/'
  };// Scale support, by adding new languages and URIs to this list
  
  let linkURI = listURI[document.documentElement.getAttribute("lang")];

  if (linkURI != undefined) {
    document.querySelector('.donate-now').href = linkURI;
    console.log(linkURI)
  } else {
    console.log("LANGUAGE DOESN'T EXIST")
  }
}

changeLink()
```

```html
<html lang="en-EN">

<head></head>

<body>
  <a href="" class="donate-now">I'm a link</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, Matthew, thank you a lot, I did research about how to get the language and found out that as you wrote above it's through document.documentElement.getAttribute("lang") . Thank you for your code, but it throws an error - ParseError thrown

syntax error, unexpected 'listURI' (T_STRING) - I m trying to find a cause, but haven't yet

Comment: @AnaGud Make sure there's a comma ( , ) between every key/value pair in the `listURI` object. i.e. `listURI = {'a':'apple','b':'banana','c':'cranberry'}`. Also, _usually_ the key (a, b, c) don't require quotes; in the snippet above they're required, because of the dashes ( - ).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, right, coma is there, I just copied the code and pasted it to functions.php, my header contains this   echo '<a href="'.esc_url($donation_url).'" class="donate-now">
                        '.esc_attr__('Join us', 'politicalwp').'
                      </a>';  and I also tried to replaced it with just simple <a href="" class="donate-now">I'm a link</a> , but still no success in both cases

Comment: @AnaGud I'm not sure what would be causing that. If you can add the rendered HTML code to your post, it might help in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Matthew, thanks a lot!!!! it's working, the problem was with a place where I added the code. Stupid, but I added it to functions.php and sure it's wrong as it's js. You are the best!!!