# Unable to change the link of a button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am a total newbie (I don't code) and I made a wordpress website in two different languages (french and english) using the Polylang plugin.

But I am facing the following problem :  in my website, there is a button linking to a Facebook page in english and when the website is switched to french, I would like the button to link to another Facebook page (that will be in french).

From what I searched so far, I understand that this would be possible using javascript. 
And I tried many variations of the following code with no result :

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('html[lang=|fr] .fa-facebook').attr('href', 'https://myfacebookpage.com'); 
   });
</script>
```

"fa-facebook" is the css class of the social media button.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix that please ? 
Thank you !

Edit : here is the html code of the french version : jsfiddle.net/yup5zxng

Comment: can you show the html? Does the selector work? can you do `console.log($('html[lang=|fr] .fa-facebook'))`?

Comment: Yes the selector works, I tried modifying it in Css

Comment: does this help -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956928/8851062 ?

Comment: Running this in the console: `jQuery('html[lang=|fr] .fa-facebook')` returns an error **Syntax error, unrecognized expression: html[lang=|fr] .fa-facebook**. This selector does work though `$('.fa-facebook');`

Comment: Paste html code in your question.

Comment: please add your HTML in the question and state your exact problem

Comment: @DFFD you can add on jsfiddle and paste the url

Answer (score 0):

I also tried with not result :

```
  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('html:lang(fr-FR) .fa-facebook').attr('href', 'https://myfacebookpage.com'); }); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you should do is check the language of the `<html>` tag on document ready and after loop through all the facebook links and update their `href`. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  const documentLanguage = $("html").attr("lang");
  const facebookLinks = $(".fa-facebook");

  facebookLinks.each(function(index, link) {
    if (documentLanguage === "fr-FR") {
      $(link).parent().attr("href", "https://facebook.com/my-french-site/");
    } else if (documentLanguage === "en-EN") {
      $(link).parent().attr("href", "https://facebook.com/my-english-site/");
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a live sample: https://jsfiddle.net/rhernando/kwndv609/3

---

**EDIT**
I forgot about the tree structure of your DOM the class element is an `<i>` tag so you have to point to it's parent element. The updated code should work.

Comment: It does here at least: https://jsfiddle.net/rhernando/yphrq3j6/1/ If you check the facebook icon links, you'll them pointing to `https://facebook.com/my-french-site/` Also if you change the language to `en-EN` in the `<html>` tag and run the code again the links point to the english fake url. Maybe this could be related with the fact that your setup uses Wordpress.

Comment: yes, it upsets me because this is the solution I have been searching for, yet when I implement it it doesn't give the awaited results... Thank you for your time and your effort !

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in the attribute selector:
`|` should be before `=`, not after:

```js
$('html[lang|=fr] .fa-facebook')
```

More about attribute selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Thank you, I changed it but there still is something wrong with my code because it doesn't work